# How to keep track of top level folder in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm storing a tree structure, more precisely a `folder` structure, as a PostgreSQL table.

It's something like this:

`folders(folder_id - UUID, folder_parent_id - UUID: foreign key folders.folder_id, folder_name - string)`

I navigate this using Common Table Expressions (CTE) and recursive queries.

However, I'd like to perform some "per-subtree" processing and for this I was thinking I could have a query where each folder also stores its top level parent.

Think of something like this:

```
A -> B -> C
  -> D -> E
```

I'd like the rows returned to look something like this:

```
folder_id = A, folder_parent_id = A, folder_top_level_parent_id = A
folder_id = B, folder_parent_id = A, folder_top_level_parent_id = A
folder_id = C, folder_parent_id = B, folder_top_level_parent_id = A
folder_id = D, folder_parent_id = A, folder_top_level_parent_id = A
folder_id = E, folder_parent_id = D, folder_top_level_parent_id = A
```

How would the query that returns this look like?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What's the query that does can return this, basically? :)

Comment: The final query is actually a lot more complex and it involves another table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543975/how-to-keep-track-of-top-level-folder-in-postgresql

I simplified the question here to get at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72cf8a1254e9560511ac2e2d04fa826a)

It's a straight-forward recursive CTE. Just add the top-level element to your output and keep it in the recursioni:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 
        folder_id, 
        folder_parent_id, 
        folder_id AS folder_top_level_parent_id
    FROM folders 
    WHERE folder_id = folder_parent_id
    
    UNION 
    
    SELECT
        f.folder_id,
        f.folder_parent_id,
        c.folder_top_level_parent_id
    FROM folders f
    JOIN cte c ON f.folder_parent_id = c.folder_id
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Comment: Ah, man, I feel so silly. The first SELECT already returns precisely what I need, I just needed to duplicate it and store it ‍♂️, you're right.